# Android Tablayout - app crashes

Tags: android

Currently I am working with tablayout which contains three tabs (fragments). In one tab it's making a volley request to my php server. It's working fine and receive response also. But if I press back button or if it's orientation changes from portrait to landscape in the middle of volley operation, my app crashes.
M a kind new to android development.,please help me to work out this.

Comment: post error log..

Comment: And post your code too ...

Answer (score 0):

Android can destroy your activities and fragments when they are stopped.
If you go back your fragment or activity are also destroyed.
If you rotate your device it is also destroyed and swapped with a new instance.
It's a problem that has a lot of approaches to be solved.

The easiest thing is to check `fragment.isAdded()` before doing any UI related work.

A better solution would be to introduce some design solution, for example [architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html)

Comment: Can we use fragment.isAdded() in fragment itself?

Comment: Or shall I use try and catch.
I will share my code with you.

Comment: You should use try-catch if you want to do something in case of error. Here it would be better to just avoid doing the operation that causes the crash.